# Pass the value of dropdown text to textbox

Tags: jquery

I'm working now on getting the text value of dropdown and pass it into textbox. The value and text of dropdown is from database.

I need to pass the text to my textbox. Help Please

This is my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zy46N/

```
<?php
    while($row = $resultcode->fetch_assoc())
        {
    $code .= '<option value = "'.$row['maincode'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
?>
<br/>
Category
<select name="supplier" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php echo $code; ?>
</select>
    </br>
Sub Code
<input name="catvalue" id="catvalue" value="" readonly>

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#supplier").change(function () {
      var selectedText2 =  $("#supplier option:selected").text();
         alert("You selected :" + selectedText2 );
           $('[name="catvalue"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#supplier").change(function () {
      var selectedText2 =  $("#supplier option:selected").text();
         alert("You selected :" + selectedText2 );
           $('[name="catvalue"]').val(selectedText2);
    });
});
```

Try it here

http://jsfiddle.net/Zy46N/2/

Comment: I forgot to include that the value and text of dropdown is from database

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already retrieve the text of the selected `option` and assigned it to `selectedText2`

You can just use:

```
$('[name="catvalue"]').val(selectedText2);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy46N/1/)**

Comment: why not just target the input by id?

Comment: I forgot to include that the value and text of dropdown is from database

Comment: @surname There is no difference here. Can you check to see if it works?

Comment: @surname what's your created HTML markup for `select` element look like after you do `echo $code;`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#supplier").change(function () {
       var selectedText2 =  $("#supplier option:selected").text();
       $('#catvalue').val(selectedText2);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some options to attain what you want. What some other stackoverflowers answers given or this.
EDITED:

Here is what you gonna do. Give certain attribute to the select box for me its `ref`.

```
<select name="supplier" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <?php
      while($row = $resultcode->fetch_assoc()){
         ?><option value = "<?php echo $row['maincode']; ?>" ref = "<?php echo $row['category']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></option><?php
    }
?>
</select>

<input id = "txt_cat_value" type = "text">
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#supplier").change(function () {
       $('#txt_cat_value').val($(this).attr('ref'));
  });
});
```

Hope its okay now.

Comment: I need the text not the value